# Asp.net core 2.2 api not able to integrate miniprofiler, dapper and mySql to work

Tags: asp.net-core, miniprofiler

I am trying to get miniprofiler and Dapper on MySql to work together to profile sql statements.

I have managed to get miniprofiler and swagger to work together but the sql generated and executed by dapper are not intercepted for some reason, I believe this is because Miniprofiler.Current always returns null for some reason.

I was wondering if anyone else can help.

sample project is attached.
run docker compose and run api manually.
[image]

[image]

test api download => https://gofile.io/?c=Qf6boJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st issue was that `app.UseMiniprofiler()` needs to come before `app.UseMvc`

2nd issue was that the db connection factory must look like this:

```
 public IDbConnection Create()
        {
            return new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(
                new MySqlConnection(_storageSettings.ConnectionString),
                MiniProfiler.Current
            );
        }
```

The packages that I use are as follows:

```
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
<PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="0.61.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MiniProfiler.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="4.1.0" />
```